# How to construct a line tangent to a curve from a point using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

ArcGIS Enterprise SDK has something like [this](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/sdk/latest/windows/ICurve_QueryTangent.html):

```
public void QueryTangent (
    esriSegmentExtension extension,
    double DistanceAlongCurve,
    bool asRatio,
    double Length,
    ILine tangent
);
```

> Given a distance along the curve specified either as a ratio of the length or as a specific fixed distance, QueryTangent returns the Line tangent to the Point.

I wonder if anything like this exists in QGIS Python API? If not, is it possible to implement this function from scratch?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it doesn't exist. But you can implement it. Combining [QgsGeometry](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsGeometry.html) and [QgsGeometryUtils](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsGeometryUtils.html) methods may help.

To begin with, I would examine [`interpolatePointOnLine`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsGeometryUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometryUtils.interpolatePointOnLine), [`interpolatePointOnLineByValue`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsGeometryUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometryUtils.interpolatePointOnLineByValue), [`linePerpendicularAngle`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsGeometryUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometryUtils.linePerpendicularAngle), [`perpendicularSegment`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsGeometryUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometryUtils.perpendicularSegment), [`pointOnLineWithDistance`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsGeometryUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometryUtils.pointOnLineWithDistance) methods.

Comment: Any hints? @Kadir Şahbaz

Comment: Pedantic Stackexchange rules say your question was answered ;) Better add in a "how to" clarification or ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 3):

As @Kadir Şahbaz mentioned it, there is no direct ways to calculate a tangent line to a curve using PyQGIS API. However, there is a workaround to my problem:

1. Let's say we already have a point `p` lying on a curve `c`;
2. Use `QgsGeometryUtils.pointOnLineWithDistance` to get anther point `q` that is **very close** to `p` on `c`;
3. Connect `p` with `q`, then we have a line **approximately** tangent to `p`.